# Is a SPL Token mint a PDA or a program

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program

I wonder if an SPL token mint is technically a Solana program that was created through the Token Program or if it is a PDA of the Token Program?

Answer (score 2):

It is a PDA of the Token Program. Here you can find the Account definition:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program/src/state.rs

Comment: the `Mint` is an account owned by the Token Program, you can use a PDA as the address of the `Mint` account, but it does not have to be a PDA